# Switching from a table with many columns to an auxiliiary table with multiple rows

Tags: database, postgresql

We have a Postgres database with a table "foo" and auxiliiary tables "bar_1" ... "bar_k" that hold additional data for specific types of foos.  Basically, we can think of "foo" as a parent class with common attributes, and each "bar_i" table as being a subclass of "foo" that adds additional properties.

We are thinking of redesigning the schema so that instead of several "bar" tables, we have a table  of "foo_metadata" that lists the different columns that would be in each kind of "bar" table, and a 
"foo_attributes" table that has the values that would normally be in the "bar" tables.

The advantage of such a system is that it would be very generic: we would essentially be putting metadata  about each class into the database, so that applications would not need to be updated and tests written for each changed or added class.

I imagine this would be a performance hit: instead of reading one row from "foo" and one from a "bar" table, we'd read several rows from the "foo_metadata" and "foo_attributes" tables. Likewise for updating (although we'd only update values and timestamps, which aren't indexed.)

My question is: how much of a performance hit would we get? Are there ways to minimize the performance hit? What metrics can we use to estimate the performance hit *before* commit *a lot* of developer time to redesigning the system.

(We're not concerned with Postgres enforcing the types on values, since they are generally strings, and the application needs to check the values before they are inserted into the database anyway...)

Comment: EAV is an anti-pattern. Good luck writing reports based off it. Keep at your original plan.

Comment: I don't drink the pattern Kool Aid. Sometimes anti-patterns are more appropriate for certain domains. This particular domain is one with a lot of classes with differing but small numbers of attributes, and it appears to be suited to EAV, from what I've been reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model you described is a generic EAV model (Entity–attribute–value model).

There are already tons of information about it on the internet. Just google `EAV`. You can even start from [`this`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) article in wiki.

The biggest problems with EAV:

1. It can be hard to write queries. (multiple joins to same value table instead of multiple columns from single table)
2. You cant easily apply database constraints to this model (so no reference integrity and checks).